# rotation code optimization (Java)

Tags: java, rotation, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, cycle

So I have a bit of code that operates quite often that evaluates a state of rotation. It has **two bytes, each ranging from 0-3**, corresponding to a direction (0=left, 1=down, 2=right, 3=up) and **produces a byte showing which step of rotation it is at** (so we can figure out which two directions to cycle to next). Note that **the two bytes are not supposed to be equal** but if this happens the rotation value is set to -1. I know that bit operations tend to be faster than branching operations so I used bit operations to calculate the value. Here is what I have so far:

```
byte rotation = -1;
if(con1!=con2){
    if((con1&0x1)==(con2&0x1))rotation=(byte) (4+(con1&0x1));
    else{
        rotation = (byte) ((con1^con2)>>1);
        rotation = (byte) (rotation | (rotation==0x0?con1&0x2:((con1<<1)^con2))&0x2);
    }
}
```

con1 and con2 are the two input bytes. rotation is the rotation byte and corresponds to the following:

```
-1 = invalid input
 0 = (┐), left  and down  (a 0 and a 1)
 1 = (┌), down  and right (a 1 and a 2)
 2 = (└), right and up    (a 2 and a 3)
 3 = (┘), up    and left  (a 3 and a 0)
 4 = (─), left  and right (a 0 and a 2)
 5 = (│), down  and up    (a 1 and a 3)
```

Now the question is, does anyone have a faster way to compute this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, fast code is opposite to clean code and reduced code.

I has considered that your table shown all valid possibilities and you will use the code with 0 <= input1/2 <= 3 constraint in your mind.

Maybe this code is faster, I'm not sure:

```
    byte[] matrix = {
            -1, 0, -1, -1, //input1 = 0, input2 from 0 to 3
            -1, -1, 1, 5, //input1 = 1, input2 from 0 to 3
            -1, -1, -1, 2, //input1 = 2, input2 from 0 to 3
            3, -1, -1, -1 //input1 = 3, input2 from 0 to 3
    };

    byte input1 = 0;
    byte input2 = 1;

    byte result = matrix[input1 * 4 + input2];
```

Using this implementation really you need execute only one line of code every time you need transform your input in the correct rotation, maybe is faster.

I think use "* 4" and "<< 2" may be equivalent if compiler optimise the first one.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is Java, which is intended to be platform independent. You can't really speak to speed of branching compared to bit-operations unless you know the details of the implementation.

Second, you say you are trying to avoid branching, but you put three branches in there anyway (two if-statements and a conditional operator....).

Third, it is not at all clear what you are trying to do (for example, intuitively left+right and up+down would both result in "don't do anything", but you have given them different results), and if the right thing to do might be to rethink something a bit wider than your narrow question.

Fourth, when you are dealing with bit-operations, having a "it's not supposed to happen, but if it does, assign this value" is kind of counterproductive. If you want maximum speed you should just say "it's not supposed to happen, so if it does then any value is acceptable".

Enough lecturing, if you take my advice in the fourth point, then the following would do the trick with no branches:

```
result = con1 | ((con2 << 2) & (con2 << 1));
```